# Delphi. Как программно изменять настройку "Аудио Формат по умолчанию" в Windows

Tags: delphi, windows, аудио

Не пойму как программно изменить настройку Default Audio Format (Формат по умолчанию) в Windows 7 (и выше) для конкретного записывающего аудио устройства.

Как добраться до него, например: через MMDeviceAPI?

Моя USB-звуковая карта при подключении получает настройки "1 канал, 8 бит...", а мне нужно перевести ее в режима "2 канала, 16 бит...".

Comment: [PKEY_AudioEngine_DeviceFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd316580(v=vs.85).aspx) не подходит?

Comment: Абсолютно точно!

Comment: [сразу нашел хороший пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/661489/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-windows)

Comment: там скорее хороший вопрос :D