# WASAPI Запись звука

Tags: windows, c++-cli, аудио, звукозапись

В результате записи получается полная ерунда. В чём ошибка?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "windows.h"
#include "mmdeviceapi.h"
#include "audioclient.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "ole32.lib")

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

#define REFTIMES_PER_SEC  10000000
#define REFTIMES_PER_MILLISEC  10000

#define EXIT_ON_ERROR(hres)     if (FAILED(hres)) { goto Exit; }
#define SAFE_RELEASE(punk)      if ((punk) != NULL) { (punk)->Release(); (punk) = NULL; }

const CLSID CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator);
const IID IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator);
const IID IID_IAudioClient = __uuidof(IAudioClient);
const IID IID_IAudioCaptureClient = __uuidof(IAudioCaptureClient);

List<BYTE>^ RecordAudioStream() {

    HRESULT hr;

    REFERENCE_TIME hnsRequestedDuration = REFTIMES_PER_SEC;
    REFERENCE_TIME hnsActualDuration;
    UINT32 bufferFrameCount;
    UINT32 numFramesAvailable;
    UINT32 packetLength = 0;
    BYTE *pData;
    List<BYTE>^ buf = gcnew List<BYTE>();
    DWORD flags;
    WAVEFORMATEX *pwfx = NULL;

    IMMDeviceEnumerator *pEnumerator = NULL;
    IMMDevice *pDevice = NULL;
    IAudioClient *pAudioClient = NULL;
    IAudioCaptureClient *pCaptureClient = NULL;

    // Get default audio device IMMDevice object.

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator,
        NULL, CLSCTX_ALL,
        IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator,
        (void**)&pEnumerator);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr);

    hr = pEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eCapture, eConsole, &pDevice);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr);

    hr = pDevice->Activate(IID_IAudioClient,
        CLSCTX_ALL, NULL,
        (void**)&pAudioClient);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr);

    hr = pAudioClient->GetMixFormat(&pwfx);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr);

    // Create audio client object.

    hr = pAudioClient->Initialize(AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED, 0, hnsRequestedDuration, 0, pwfx, NULL);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr);

    // Get the size of the allocated buffer.
    hr = pAudioClient->GetBufferSize(&bufferFrameCount);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr);

    hr = pAudioClient->GetService(IID_IAudioCaptureClient, (void**)&pCaptureClient);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr);

    Console::WriteLine("Used format:\nChannels: {0}\nFreq: {1}\nSample bits: {2}", pwfx->nChannels, pwfx->nSamplesPerSec, pwfx->wBitsPerSample);

    // Calculate the actual duration of the allocated buffer.
    hnsActualDuration = (double)REFTIMES_PER_SEC * bufferFrameCount / pwfx->nSamplesPerSec;

    hr = pAudioClient->Start(); // Start recording.
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr);

    // 4 sec recording.
    System::Diagnostics::Stopwatch^ s = gcnew System::Diagnostics::Stopwatch();
    s->Start();

    // Each loop fills about half of the shared buffer.
    while (s->ElapsedMilliseconds < 4000)
    {
        // Sleep for half the buffer duration.
        Sleep(hnsActualDuration / REFTIMES_PER_MILLISEC / 2);

        hr = pCaptureClient->GetNextPacketSize(&packetLength);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr);

        while (packetLength != 0)
        {
            // Get the available data in the shared buffer.
            hr = pCaptureClient->GetBuffer(&pData, &numFramesAvailable, &flags, NULL, NULL);
            EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr);

            if (flags & AUDCLNT_BUFFERFLAGS_SILENT)
            {
                pData = NULL; // Tell CopyData to write silence.
            }
            else
            {
                // Copy the available capture data.
                for (int i = 0; i < packetLength; i++)
                    buf->Add(*(pData + i));
            }

            hr = pCaptureClient->ReleaseBuffer(numFramesAvailable);
            EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr);

            hr = pCaptureClient->GetNextPacketSize(&packetLength);
            EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr);
        }
    }

    hr = pAudioClient->Stop(); // Stop recording.

Exit:
    CoTaskMemFree(pwfx);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pEnumerator);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pDevice);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pAudioClient);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pCaptureClient);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pRenderClient);

    return buf;
}
```

[Capturing a Stream (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370800(v=vs.85).aspx)

---

Тестовое воспроизведение в NAudio:

```
WaveOut^ waveOut = gcnew WaveOut();
waveOut->DeviceNumber = 0;
waveOut->Init(gcnew RawSourceWaveStream(buf->ToArray(), 0, buf->Count, gcnew WaveFormat(44100, 32, 2)));
System::Threading::ThreadStart^ thStart = gcnew System::Threading::ThreadStart(waveOut, &WaveOut::Play);
(gcnew System::Threading::Thread(thStart))->Start();
```

Comment: _Если есть код сохранения звука в файл, выложите его тоже, чтобы можно было протестировать_ - Я использую NAudio для тестирования записи. _У вас при наличии флага AUDCLNT_BUFFERFLAGS_SILENT в buf не добавляются пропуски, так задумано?_ - Не знаю. Так не задумано... _В чем именно выражается "полная ерунда"?_ - Просто короткий фрагмент шума.

Comment: _У вас при наличии флага AUDCLNT_BUFFERFLAGS_SILENT в buf не добавляются пропуски, так задумано?_ - Зачем нам пропуски то?.. _Тогда выложите код, как в NAudio создаете поток_ - Обновил. Формат верный (как в `pwfx`).

Comment: Этих трех параметров недостаточно, чтобы охарактеризовать формат. Нужно конвертнуть в WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE и посмотреть SubType. С высокой вероятностью там не PCM, поэтому ничего и не работает.

Comment: Верно. Там WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE (Microsoft format). Как поправить? Если просто перед вызовом метода `IAudioClient::Initialize` поменять `pwfx->wFormatTag` на WAVE_FORMAT_PCM, то возвращаемый HRESULT скажет нам об ошибке (E_INVALID_ARG).

Comment: Только я не делал конвертации к WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE. Я просто в WAVEFORMATEX (у нас - переменная `pwfx`) посмотрел `wFormatTag`.

Comment: WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE - это обобщенный формат. Чтобы узнать конкретный формат, надо *обязательно* конвертировать в WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE и смотреть SubType (его значение Data1).

Comment: Да. Я уже понял) Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С данным кодом есть две проблемы.

1. Флаг AUDCLNT_BUFFERFLAGS_SILENT надо не игнорировать, а писать в буфер соответствующее количество тишины (т.е. пустых байтов). Конечно, если пустоты *слишком* много, можно ее подрезать для экономии размера, но всю пустоту игнорировать неправильно.
2. Из функции возвращается массив сырых байтов, без всякого признака формата (видимо, подразумевается PCM). Так делать не имеет особого смысла - формат в устройстве может быть любым, чаще всего это IEEE Float, но полагаться на это не стоит. Нужно сохранять и формат и данные.

Примерный код захвата 5 секунд звука с устройства и записи в WAV-файл (протестирован в MSVC++ 2012):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "windows.h"
#include "mmdeviceapi.h"
#include "uuids.h"
#include "audioclient.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "ole32.lib")

struct WAVHEADER
{    
    char chunkId[4]; //RIFF    
    unsigned long chunkSize;    
    char format[4]; //WAVE      
    char subchunk1Id[4]; //fmt        
    unsigned long subchunk1Size; //18

    unsigned short audioFormat; //wFormatTag    
    unsigned short numChannels;    
    unsigned long sampleRate; //Hz    
    unsigned long byteRate;    
    unsigned short blockAlign;    
    unsigned short bitsPerSample;
    unsigned short cbSize;    
};

const UINT WAVHEADER_SIZE = 38;

struct WAV_FACT_CHUNK
{
    char FactChunkID[4]; //fact
    unsigned long FactChunkSize; //4
    unsigned long dwSampleLength;
};

struct WAV_DATA_CHUNK
{    
    char subchunk2Id[4]; //data    
    unsigned long subchunk2Size;
    // Далее следуют данные...
};


// REFERENCE_TIME time units per second and per millisecond
#define REFTIMES_PER_SEC  10000000
#define REFTIMES_PER_MILLISEC  10000

#define EXIT_ON_ERROR(hres)  \
              if (FAILED(hres)) { goto Exit; }
#define SAFE_RELEASE(punk)  \
              if ((punk) != NULL)  \
                { (punk)->Release(); (punk) = NULL; }

const CLSID CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator);
const IID IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator);
const IID IID_IAudioClient = __uuidof(IAudioClient);
const IID IID_IAudioCaptureClient = __uuidof(IAudioCaptureClient);

//Запись 5 секунд звука в WAV-файл
HRESULT RecordAudioStream(TCHAR* file)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    REFERENCE_TIME hnsRequestedDuration = REFTIMES_PER_SEC;
    REFERENCE_TIME hnsActualDuration;
    UINT32 bufferFrameCount;
    UINT32 numFramesAvailable;
    IMMDeviceEnumerator *pEnumerator = NULL;
    IMMDevice *pDevice = NULL;
    IAudioClient *pAudioClient = NULL;
    IAudioCaptureClient *pCaptureClient = NULL;
    WAVEFORMATEX *pwfx = NULL;
    UINT32 packetLength = 0;
    BOOL bDone = FALSE;
    BYTE *pData;
    DWORD flags;

    hr = CoCreateInstance(
           CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, NULL,
           CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator,
           (void**)&pEnumerator);
    if(FAILED(hr))printf("CoCreateInstance failed");
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    hr = pEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(
                        eCapture, eConsole, &pDevice);
    if(FAILED(hr))printf("GetDefaultAudioEndpoint failed");
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    hr = pDevice->Activate(
                    IID_IAudioClient, CLSCTX_ALL,
                    NULL, (void**)&pAudioClient);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    //Получение формата
    hr = pAudioClient->GetMixFormat(&pwfx);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE wex={0};    
    WORD wFormatTag=0;

    if(pwfx->wFormatTag == WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE){        
        memcpy(&wex,pwfx,sizeof(WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE));
        wFormatTag=wex.SubFormat.Data1;            
    }
    else{
        wFormatTag=pwfx->wFormatTag;        
    }    

    //инициализация...
    hr = pAudioClient->Initialize(
                         AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED,
                         0,
                         hnsRequestedDuration,
                         0,
                         pwfx,
                         NULL);

    if(FAILED(hr))printf("Initialize failed");
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    // Get the size of the allocated buffer.
    hr = pAudioClient->GetBufferSize(&bufferFrameCount);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    hr = pAudioClient->GetService(
                         IID_IAudioCaptureClient,
                         (void**)&pCaptureClient);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

    int counter = 0; //кол-во записанных семплов
    int max_samples = 5 * pwfx->nSamplesPerSec; //максимальное кол-во семплов
    BYTE zero = 0;

    //формирование заголовков WAV-файла
    WAVHEADER header={
        {'R','I','F','F'},0,
        {'W','A','V','E'},{'f','m','t',' '},18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    };

    WAV_FACT_CHUNK fact={{'f','a','c','t'},4,0};
    WAV_DATA_CHUNK data={{'d','a','t','a'},0};

    header.chunkSize = WAVHEADER_SIZE - 8 + sizeof(WAV_FACT_CHUNK) +sizeof(WAV_DATA_CHUNK) + max_samples * pwfx->nBlockAlign;
    header.audioFormat = wFormatTag;
    header.numChannels = pwfx->nChannels;
    header.sampleRate = pwfx->nSamplesPerSec;
    header.byteRate = pwfx->nAvgBytesPerSec;
    header.blockAlign = pwfx->nBlockAlign;
    header.bitsPerSample = pwfx->wBitsPerSample;    
    fact.dwSampleLength = max_samples * pwfx->nChannels;
    data.subchunk2Size = max_samples * pwfx->nBlockAlign;

    //запись заголовков
    FILE* fp = _wfopen(file,L"wb");
    size_t res = fwrite(&header,WAVHEADER_SIZE,1,fp);
    if(res<1)printf("header fwrite error!\n");

    res = fwrite(&fact,sizeof(fact),1,fp);
    if(res<1)printf("fact fwrite error!\n");

    res = fwrite(&data,sizeof(data),1,fp);
    if(res<1)printf("data fwrite error!\n");

    // Calculate the actual duration of the allocated buffer.
    hnsActualDuration = (double)REFTIMES_PER_SEC *
                     bufferFrameCount / pwfx->nSamplesPerSec;

    hr = pAudioClient->Start();  // Start recording.
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)    

    // Each loop fills about half of the shared buffer.
    while (true)
    {
        // Sleep for half the buffer duration.
        Sleep(hnsActualDuration/REFTIMES_PER_MILLISEC/2);        

        hr = pCaptureClient->GetNextPacketSize(&packetLength);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

        while (packetLength != 0)
        {
            // Get the available data in the shared buffer.
            hr = pCaptureClient->GetBuffer(
                                   &pData,
                                   &numFramesAvailable,
                                   &flags, NULL, NULL);
            EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

            if (flags & AUDCLNT_BUFFERFLAGS_SILENT)
            {                
                for(int i=0; i<numFramesAvailable * pwfx->nBlockAlign;i++) // Tell CopyData to write silence.
                {
                    res=fwrite(&zero,1,1,fp);
                    if(res<1)printf("Can't write silence!\n");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Copy the available capture data to the audio sink.
                res=fwrite(pData,pwfx->nBlockAlign,numFramesAvailable,fp);
                if(res<numFramesAvailable)printf("Can't write data!\n");
            }     

            hr = pCaptureClient->ReleaseBuffer(numFramesAvailable);
            EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

            hr = pCaptureClient->GetNextPacketSize(&packetLength);
            EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

            counter += numFramesAvailable;

        }
        if(counter >= max_samples) break;
    }    

    printf("Finished recording\n");
    hr = pAudioClient->Stop();  // Stop recording.
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

Exit:

    CoTaskMemFree(pwfx);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pEnumerator)
    SAFE_RELEASE(pDevice)
    SAFE_RELEASE(pAudioClient)
    SAFE_RELEASE(pCaptureClient)

    return hr;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    RecordAudioStream(L"c:\\MP3\\test.wav");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

**Примечания**

- *fact chunk* и последнее поле в заголовке WAV нужны, поскольку некоторые проигрыватели требуют их обязательного наличия для non-PCM форматов.
- Значение *WAVHEADER_SIZE* отличается от *sizeof(WAVHEADER)* из-за выравнивания структур до 4-байтовой границы. sizeof его учитывает, а при записи в файл оно не нужно.
- В данном примере используется формат, возвращенный *GetMixFormat*, так как он гарантированно может быть использован для работы с устройством в не-эксклюзивном режиме. Если есть необходимость, можно выбрать другой формат, поддерживаемый устройством.

Comment: Вы добавляете в WAV файл fact chunk, но при этом не проверяете является ли формат данных действительно non PCM. Так задумано? Вроде же, согласно документации, fact chunk добавляется исключительно для non PCM форматом аудиоданных. Или PCM формат не бывает в данном случае?

Comment: @D.Stark Формат RIFF устроен так, что лишние чанки должны игнорироваться считывающими программами. Я думаю, данный код произведет корректный файл и для PCM.

Comment: Мне не ясна одна деталь формата: принцип установки значения Subchunk1Size. Почитав кое-какие документационные [сведения](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html) я обнаружил, что всего для этого поля возможно 3 значения: 16 (PCM), 18 (non PCM) и 40 (extensible). Формула выглядит, вроде как, так: subchunk1size = fmt chunk size (16 bytes) + extra format data size. Т.е. в зависимости от формата данных у нас разное значение размера format chunk? И что же там в этих extra format data может быть? У вас, как я посмотрю, это 2 пустых байта. Вернее, не совсем пустых))

Comment: ... Не совсем пустых, потому что значение `WAVHEADER_SIZE` на 2 больше реального размера структуры, в результате чего пишутся 2 байта следующих в памяти за `header`. А это как раз `fact` типа `WAV_FACT_CHUNK`. В итоге там просто символы "fa". Но это всё не суть вообще. Просто формат данных, как я посмотрел у себя - IEEE Float (3). Это не PCM (1) и, следовательно, Subchunk1Size должен быть равен 18. Давайте поставим 16 и ничего не изменится. WAV файл будет воспроизведён корректно. Может быть я конечно не знаю кое-чего и программа воспроизведения WAV просто игнорировала ошибку...

Comment: Но всё же. Зачем вот это "extra format data" что после format chunk?  То, чей размер мы добавляем в Subchunk1Size. То, что в вашем примере записывается пустотой. Далее у нас идёт разве что fact chunk, что, кстати, как раз является "extra format data". Но там явно не 2 байта - там 12.

Comment: Извините, что задаю такие допытливые вопросы))

Comment: Мне кажется, эта extra format data в format chunk для всех существующих форматов может быть игнорирована. Т.е. может быть, а может и не быть. Следовательно и subchubk1size может быть всегда равен 16 не смотря на то, какой формат - PCM, не PCM... А fact chunk вообще не при делах. Это дополнительная секция для поддержки разных форматов.

Comment: @D.Stark Если честно, я так глубоко не вникал в спецификацию. В той статье, которую я читал, было написано, что размер fmt subchunk может быть 16 или 18, но для non-PCM должно быть именно 18, иначе Windows Media Player ее не скушает (при этом сами два дополнительных байта могут содержать нули). Соответственно, так я и сделал. Возможно, на самом деле ни это поле, ни fact chunk вообще не нужны, но я не проверял.

Comment: Хорошо. Я сделаю именно 18 с 2 пустыми байтами. И fact chunk тоже оставлю. Не охота долго разбираться.

Comment: Да. Я это уже понял.

Comment: После получения первых доступных данных из буфера, `ICaptureClient::GetBuffer` возвращает во флагах значение `AUDCLNT_BUFFERFLAGS_SILENT`. По условию в таком случае у нас в файл пишется тишина. Это обязательно или можно игнорировать? А если мне нужно вести запись не сначала например?

Comment: @D.Stark Это сами решайте, нужна вам тишина или нет. Хотите обрезать тишину в начале - обрезайте.

Comment: В системе может быть сколько угодно разных аудио устройств. У каждого устройства свой список поддерживаемых форматов. Некоторые, должно быть, вообще не поддерживают запись на определённых частотах из диапазона 10-100 кГц. Если мы будем передавать звук с микрофона на другой компьютер, то местные динамики вообще могут не поддерживать воспроизведение на такого формата. Так почему мы же мы всего этого не учитываем?

Comment: `IAudioClient:GetMixFormat` возвращает формат аудиопотока, который идёт от звукового "движка" до конечной точки. Поскольку ни IAudioClient ни GetMixFormat не получают никакой информации (при инициализации и при вызове соответственно) о конкретном устройстве, выдаётся, так понимаю, какое то общее системное значение этого mix format. В документации так и сказано: > "The mix format is the format that the audio engine uses internally for digital processing of shared-mode streams. This format is not necessarily a format that the audio endpoint device supports."

Comment: Достаточно чётко подчёркнуто, что формат этот ни в коем случае не применим для эксклюзивного режима (в смысле, вероятно будет несовпадение с поддерживаемыми устройством форматами). При этом не обязательно подходит для общего режима.

Comment: Зачем этот метод вообще тогда существует...

Comment: @D.Stark Потому что это просто пример, ориентированный на типовую ситуацию. Вероятность того, что MixFormat одного компьютера не будет поддерживаться на другом компьютере, довольно мала.

Comment: Не. Я понимаю, что вероятность мала, но всё же она есть. Пользователь, думаю, не обрадуется когда поймает такую ошибку. Как вы думаете это можно устранить?

Comment: > В примере с MSDN GetMixFormat используется только потому, что этот формат гарантированно поддерживается устройством. - Почему гарантированно? У нас может быть 10 устройств и у каждого могут быть свои поддерживаемые форматы. Я же писал выше выдержки с [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370872(v=vs.85).aspx): "This format is not necessarily a format that the audio endpoint device supports."

Comment: @D.Stark Неточно выразился, скорее "формат, который гарантированно скушает метод IAudioClient::Initialize при вызове с флагом AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED" (что и требуется в данном коде). Он может отличаться от формата вывода конкретного устройства битностью или типом кодирования (PCM/Float), но обычно имеет ту же частоту дискретизации.

Comment: Т.е. ошибки не произойдёт если устройство не поддерживает такой формат, который выдал GetMixFormat?

Comment: А почему не произойдёт ошибки? Будет использован другой формат? А как его получить, если так?

Comment: @D.Stark Не произойдет ошибки, потому что так написано: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370872(v=vs.85).aspx - "The client can call this method before calling the IAudioClient::Initialize method. When creating a shared-mode stream for an audio endpoint device, the Initialize method always accepts the stream format obtained from a GetMixFormat call on the same device.". У устройства есть на самом деле 2 формата, можете почитать здесь кое-что про это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/743709/240512

Comment: Ясно. Т.е. в общем режиме аудио поток сначала проходит через движок, который приводит поток к заданному там формату. Этот формат мы и получаем через GetMixFormat. Если пустить на движок другой формат (не тот, что выдаёт функция), то ошибки тоже не произойдёт, ведь движок преобразует наш формат в формат устройства. По умолчанию, я так понимаю, формат микширования идентичен формату устройства (поэтому у нас и IEEE Float, который наиболее распространён).

Comment: Единственное, что нужно учитывать, так это частоту дискретизации и количество каналов записи. Если мы запишем звук в 44.1 kHz 2 channels PCM, а будем воспроизводить на устройстве формат микширования которого является 94 kHz 1 channel (мало ли кто такой формат поставил), то WAVEFORMATEX из GetMixFormat нужно будет поменять указав 44 kHz, 2 channels. А формат будет приведён автоматический движком (PCM to IEEE Float). Это верно?

Comment: И всё же у аудиодвижков разных компьютеров могут быть взаимно не поддерживаемые форматы. Ведь движок не сможет наверное преобразовать любой формат к формату устройства ([вон их сколько всего](https://tools.ietf.org/html/2361)). Вы говорите, что это прямо таки совсем маловероятно. Может быть. Стоит ли тогда об этом беспокоиться и юзать DirectSound, который автоматически приводит формат звука от приложения к формату, который поддерживается движком, если надо, или нет?

Comment: @D.Stark Пишите сюда: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74872/audio-chat Это уже явно выходит за рамки данного вопроса.