# OpenALL С++ Запись и отдельно Проигрывание

Tags: c++, windows, аудио, visual-studio-2010, звукозапись

Пытаюсь научиться обрабатывать записанный с микрофона звук, нашёл пример, но там всё склеено, и непонятно что за что отвечает.

Мне нужно

1. Записать допустим 3 секунды
2. Получить доступ к массиву с записанными данными, проанализировать или даже изменить
3. Проиграть запись, сохранённую в  массиве

Вот пример, о котором писал.

```
    //#include <unistd.h>
#include <AL/al.h> 
#include <AL/alc.h> 
#include <time.h>
#include <ctime> 
#pragma comment (lib,"OpenAL32.lib")
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <windows.h>
//#include <al.h>
//#include <alc.h>


using namespace std;
int main()
{




ALCdevice *dev[2];
ALCcontext *ctx;
ALuint source, buffers[3];
char data[5000];
ALuint buf;
ALint val;

    float ttotal;
    unsigned int ccount;
    long int c1ount;
    c1ount =0;

dev[0] = alcOpenDevice(NULL);
ctx = alcCreateContext(dev[0], NULL);
alcMakeContextCurrent(ctx);

alGenSources(1, &source);
alGenBuffers(3, buffers);

/* Setup some initial silent data to play out of the source */
alBufferData(buffers[0], AL_FORMAT_MONO16, data, sizeof(data), 22050);
alBufferData(buffers[1], AL_FORMAT_MONO16, data, sizeof(data), 22050);
alBufferData(buffers[2], AL_FORMAT_MONO16, data, sizeof(data), 22050);
alSourceQueueBuffers(source, 3, buffers);

/* If you don't need 3D spatialization, this should help processing time */
alDistanceModel(AL_NONE); 

dev[1] = alcCaptureOpenDevice(NULL, 22050, AL_FORMAT_MONO16, sizeof(data)/2); //22050 mean 22.050 samples per     second. or 44100 for 44.1 per second.

/* Start playback and capture, and enter the audio loop */
alSourcePlay(source);
alcCaptureStart(dev[1]);    //starts ring buffer

while(1) 
{
    /* Check if any queued buffers are finished */
    alGetSourcei(source, AL_BUFFERS_PROCESSED, &val);
    if(val <= 0)
        continue;

    /* Check how much audio data has been captured (note that 'val' is the
    * number of frames, not bytes) */
    alcGetIntegerv(dev[1], ALC_CAPTURE_SAMPLES, 1, &val);

    /* Read the captured audio */
    alcCaptureSamples(dev[1], data, val);


        //***** Process/filter captured data here *****//


c1ount = c1ount +1;
if(c1ount >= 33){
          break;
         }


        //for (int ii=0;ii<val;++ii) {
        //  data[ii]*=0.1; // Make it quieter
        //}
    //***** end Process/filter captured data here *****//

    /* Pop the oldest finished buffer, fill it with the new capture data,
    then re-queue it to play on the source */
    alSourceUnqueueBuffers(source, 1, &buf);
    alBufferData(buf, AL_FORMAT_MONO16, data, val*2 /* bytes here, not
    frames */, 22050);
    alSourceQueueBuffers(source, 1, &buf);

    /* Make sure the source is still playing */
    alGetSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &val);

    if(val != AL_PLAYING)
    {

        alSourcePlay(source);
    }
}

cout<< "fgggggggg\n";


/* Shutdown and cleanup */
alcCaptureStop(dev[1]);
alcCaptureCloseDevice(dev[1]);

alSourceStop(source);
alDeleteSources(1, &source);
alDeleteBuffers(3, buffers);
alDeleteBuffers(1, &buf);

alcMakeContextCurrent(NULL);
alcDestroyContext(ctx);
alcCloseDevice(dev[0]); 

return 0;
}
```

Вот тоже пример, который должен записывать, но почему тут вечный цикл?

```
    #include <AL/al.h>
#include <AL/alc.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib,"OpenAL32.lib")

const int SRATE = 44100;
const int SSIZE = 1024;

ALbyte buffer[22050];
ALint sample;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    alGetError();
    ALCdevice *device = alcCaptureOpenDevice(NULL, SRATE, AL_FORMAT_STEREO16, SSIZE);
    if (alGetError() != AL_NO_ERROR) {
        return 0;
    }
    alcCaptureStart(device);

    while (true) {
        alcGetIntegerv(device, ALC_CAPTURE_SAMPLES, (ALCsizei)sizeof(ALint), &sample);
        alcCaptureSamples(device, (ALCvoid *)buffer, sample);

        // ... do something with the buffer 

        for(int i = 0; i<80;i++)
        {
            cout<<(int)buffer[i]<<' ';
        }
        cout<<"loop s\n";
    }

    alcCaptureStop(device);
    alcCaptureCloseDevice(device);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Краткое содержание: *"хочу (1) (2) (3). два примера. во втором вечный цикл"*. А в чем собственно вопрос?

Comment: В первом все три этапа слиты в и я не понимаю как их разделить, Во вторим тоже  не понятно массив есть но что в него пишет непонятно, по идеи я должен получить массив с уровнем сигнала через интервал времени. Но цыкал постоянно повторяется  вместо тог чтобы задержаться записать 2 секунды и повторится, он постоянно повторяеться

Answer (score 0):

В первом примере вот эта строка сохраняет данные аудио в массив data:

```
alcCaptureSamples(dev[1], data, val);
```

Длительность звука в массиве рассчитывается по формуле

> t = (N <sub>Samples</sub>) / (SampleRate * N <sub>Channels</sub>)

Размер данных в массиве (в байтах) рассчитывается по формуле:

> N <sub>Bytes</sub> = N <sub>Samples</sub> * (BitsPerSample / 8)

У вас N <sub>Channels</sub> = 1 (моно), SampleRate = 22050, BitsPerSample = 16, получаем:

```
t = val / 22050;

N_bytes = val * 2;
```

Вам нужно объявить массив, размером достаточный для хранения требуемой длительности аудио, допустим, saved_data. После получения каждой порции через alcCaptureSamples накапливаете данные в этом массиве (просто через memcpy копируете в конец массива и сохраняете суммарный размер). Когда длительность достигает требуемого значения, останавливаете цикл, делаете свою обработку, а потом массив с накопленными данными передаете в alBufferData и выполняете код воспроизведения:

```
alSourceUnqueueBuffers(source, 1, &buf);
alBufferData(buf, AL_FORMAT_MONO16, saved_data, N_bytes, 22050);
alSourceQueueBuffers(source, 1, &buf);
```

Есть вот такой [пример записи звука на чистом WASAPI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/794133/240512), возможно будет полезен. Правда, там сохранение сразу в файл сделано, а не в массив.