# Запись аудио и сохранение в файл с помощью WASAPI С++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, аудио, звукозапись

Возможно ли в библиотеке WASAPI записывать аудио данные сначала в буфер, а потом по какому то событию (например клику на кнопку) сохранять их в файл. Проблема в том, что примеры которые я находил (ну, например [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64318206/record-an-audio-stream-with-wasapi?#) или [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/793697/wasapi-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0) пишут данные сразу в файл. Ну и не только эти примеры. В принципе то, что я видел, там сразу создается файл и копируются в него данные, по окончанию записи файл закрывается. Хотелось бы разделить логику сохранения захваченных данных и их последующую запись в файл.

**UPD:**
сделал запись в буфер как в [примере](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64318206/record-an-audio-stream-with-wasapi?). Запись в файл также. Только в методе `RecordAudioStream` вместо

```
// Copy the available capture data to the audio sink.
hr = pMySink->CopyData(
     pData, numFramesAvailable, &bDone, pwfx, (HMMIO)hFile);
EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)
```

копирую данные в буфер и буфер сохраняю в мапу:

```
BYTE * buffer = new BYTE[(numFramesAvailable * pwfx->nBlockAlign)];
memcpy(buffer, pData, numFramesAvailable * pwfx->nBlockAlign);
m_curAudioData.insert({buffer, numFramesAvailable});
```

А затем в отдельном потоке мапу сохраняю в файл:

```
std::map<BYTE *, UINT32> audioData;
audioData.insert(m_curAudioData.begin(), m_curAudioData.end());

if (m_writerThread.joinable())
    m_writerThread.join();

m_writerThread = std::thread(std::bind([this, audioData](){
           CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
           WavWriter wav_file(pwfx);
           wav_file.CreateWAVFile();
           wav_file.WriteWaveHeader();
           for (const auto & [data, numFrames] : audioData)
           {
                wav_file.CopyData(data, numFrames);
           }
           wav_file.FinishWaveFile();
           wav_file.CloseFile();
           CoUninitialize();
}));
m_writerThread.detach();
```

Звук пишется, однако его качество достаточно плохое (есть шумы, дребизжания, и скорость воспроизведения тянется).

Comment: Можно в WINAPI, главное буферы новые под запись/чтение успевать ему подсовывать.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков, есть пример под рукой? если не долго искать

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/example-of-writing-waveform-data

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rFURaLxZ

Comment: В примерах и так идет сохранение в буфер: "pCaptureClient->GetBuffer..." Уберите вызовы функций типа fwrite, если вам не нужна запись в файл, и все тут.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, но в файл же пишутся BYTE * data, а не buffer

Comment: как этот буфер потом в файл записать по евенту какому либо?

Comment: я пробовал этот буфер сохранять в мапу, а потом по евенту записывать в файл. Не получилось

Comment: Смотрите второй пример. Буфер это pData, в файл пишется также из pData. Сохранять сам указатель pData нельзя, его потом уничтожит ReleaseBuffer. Надо через memcpy скопировать сами данные в какое-то другое место.

Comment: Ааа, Семён Семёнович... коварный winapi

Comment: Причём тут винапи? Просто не удалять буфер если он ещё нужен...

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, сколько памяти выделять для копирования данных?
BYTE * buffer = new BYTE[(numFramesAvailable * pwfx->nBlockAlign)];
memcpy(buffer, pData, numFramesAvailable * pwfx->nBlockAlign);

Comment: Да, `numFramesAvailable * pwfx->nBlockAlign`

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, похоже с выделением памяти не все так просто. Я обновил пост. Качество звука получается хуже. Я думаю что дело именно в выделении памяти. Возможно каналы играют еще роль.

Answer (score 0):

В рамках WASAPI вы получаете (record) данные и, конечно же, необходимости моментально писать из куда-то нет. Аудиоданные не имеют неприлично большого размера, так что вполне можно накапливать в памяти приличные объемы перед тем как решать что с ними делать. Одновременно, кодеки аудио данные работают достаточно быстро для текущей техники, так что тоже вполне можно набрать данных, а потом нагнать их обработку за счет ускоренного кодирования.

По большому счету помимо того, чтобы удерживать данные в памяти вам бы также хотелось ассоциировать эти данные с какими-то временными метками с тем, чтобы понимать какие данные идут последовательно, а в каких есть разрыв (к примере, на моменте система была чем-то перегружена и часть данных была потеряна) - с тем чтобы при создании файла это было учтено.